# why does the Kotlin boolean type extension function return different from I guess?

Tags: kotlin, boolean

I'm a newbie and studying Kotlin.

I think the below code should print `true`. but that actually prints `false`.

I don't know why this code prints "false".

Can anyone help me?

```kotlin
fun Boolean.and(it: Boolean): Boolean = true

fun main() {
    val b = true.and(false)
    println(b)
}
```

I'm studying Kotlin and I want to know `Boolean` type extension function logic.

Comment: You're calling the standard library _Boolean.and_ method, because you cannot override a method by defining an extension function.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your undesired output `false` is that your definition of `Boolean.and(…)` is actually shadowing [an already existing `fun`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/and.html), which is then used instead of yours.

Use a different name and get your desired result:

```kotlin
fun Boolean.logicalAnd(it: Boolean): Boolean = true

fun main() {
    val b = true.logicalAnd(false)
    println(b)
}
```

Output: `true`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped! Can you accept the answer?

Comment: If you're using an IDE such as IntelliJ, then if you let the mouse pointer hover over the call to `.and(`, it will probably show a pop-up giving details of exactly which function is being called; that can help to explain cases like this.